# Android RecyclerView: why is first item in list already selected?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a RecyclerView list of CardViews with a defaultbackground of white.  I set up a OnLongClickListener to select the CardView and load a DialogFragment to confirm deletion for the item (CardView) and change the background color to red.

Everything is working correctly except the first CardView created in the list is already showing a red background even though the user has not OnLongClicked the CardView.  Thereafter, the newest CardView added always shows the red background even when the user has not yet OnLongClicked the CardView.  What am I missing here?

background_selector.xml:

```
...
<!-- Normal state. -->
<item android:drawable="@color/list_contact_item_default"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_selected="false"  />

<!-- Selected state. -->

<item android:drawable="@color/item_selected"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_selected="true" />

</selector>
```

list_contact_tem.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singlecard_view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"  >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector">
    ...
```

Adapter file:

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListAdapter.ContactHolder>{
    ...
    private int selectedPos;

    @Override
    public ContactHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_contact_item, parent, false);

    final ContactHolder contactHolder = new ContactHolder(view);

    // Attach a LongClick listener to the items's (row) view.
    contactHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            // Save the new selected position.
            selectedPos = contactHolder.getAdapterPosition(); // get the item position.
            if (selectedPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                    recyclerItemClickListener.onItemLongClick(selectedPos, contactHolder.itemView);
                        // Temporarily save the last selected position
                        int lastSelectedPosition = selectedPos;
                        // Update the previous selected row
                        notifyItemChanged(lastSelectedPosition);
                        notifyItemChanged(selectedPos);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    return contactHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactHolder holder, int position) {
        final Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

        if(position == selectedPos) {
            holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
        }

    holder.thumb.setImageBitmap(letterBitmap);
    holder.name.setText(contact.getName());
    holder.phone.setText(contact.getPhone());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an external array to keep track of the items selected. Let us have an array which have the same size as the list.

```
private int[] selectedArray = new int[yourList.size()];

// Now initialize the Array with all zeros
for(int i=0; i<selectedArray.length; i++)
    selectedArray[i] = 0;
```

Now inside your adapter, when an item is clicked, set 1 in the proper position in the `selectedArray`. So that, we can keep track which item is selected now.

Now modify your adapter code as follows

```
// Attach a LongClick listener to the items's (row) view.
contactHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        // Update the selectedArray. Set 1 for the selected item
        // and 0 for the others.
        updateSelectedArray(contactHolder.getAdapterPosition());

        if (selectedPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                recyclerItemClickListener.onItemLongClick(selectedPos, contactHolder.itemView);

                // Repopulate the list here
                notifyDatasetChanged();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

And in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
final int SELECTED = 1;
if(selectedArray[position] == SELECTED) {
    holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
} else {
    holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
}
```

Your `updateSelectedArray()` may look like this

```
private void updateSelectedArray(int position) {
    for(int i=0; i<selectedArray.length; i++){
        if(i == position) selectedArray[i] = 1;
        else selectedArray[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

And after you delete an item from the list, you need to reset the selectedArray` as the item is no longer available in your list.

So your `deleteFromList` function may look like:

```
private void deleteFromList(int position)
{
    yourList.remove(position);
    selectedArray = new int[yourList.size()];

    // Now re-initialize the Array with all zeros
    for(int i=0; i<selectedArray.length; i++)
        selectedArray[i] = 0;
}
```

I've taken an array to keep track of the selected item. But you can take an `ArrayList` or any data structure you like to keep track of it. The idea is to keep track of the selected item properly.

**Update**

The problem of having randomly selected items in your list is caused by not binding your views properly. So when you delete an item, you need to do the following things.

- Reset your selected position in the selectedArray. i.e. `selectedPos = -1`
- Remove the item from the list.
- Call `notifyDatasetChanged` to take the effect of your changes in the
  list.

And most importantly don't forget to set the `else` part. What I meant is

```
// Pseudo code
if(position == selected) itemView.setSelected(true);
else itemView.setSelected(true); // Don't forget this else
```

Comment: Sorry I must not have been clear.  For the onLongClick(), I am only allowing the user to LongClick on one CardView from the RecyclerView list.  The method is used to change the BackgroundColor of the selected CardView and then load a DialogFragment that confirms the user wants to delete the CardView.

Comment: Yes, this should work in your case too. What's the problem you're facing right now? This is a simplified version of `toggleSelection` from my other answer. You just don't have to implement the `toggleSelection` here.

Comment: I was able to fix the first CardView incorrectly getting highlighted by changing "private int selectedPos;" to "private int selectedPos = -1;"  I have one more problem that remains.  After the highlighted CardView is deleted, the RecyclerList is refreshed and other CardViews are randomly having their BackGround color toggled to the red color even though none of the CardViews have been LongClicked.  It's as if the old position of the deleted CardView still remains in the RecyclerView list and so another Cardview that takes that position has its BackgroundColor changed mistakenly.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok I will try.  Should the "else" portion be ...setSelected(false)?

Comment: ya. Please give it a try and let me know if that worked. Feel free to ask if you face any difficulties again.

Comment: I will try.  But I don't see "updateSelectedArray(contactHolder.getAdapterPosition());"  Please advise.